# Angular js double request in inner promise

Tags: angularjs

Hi my angular js function sends a double request to the server, 1 return without any result and the second with the result.

I am using md-dialog of material and I am sharing the part when clicking on add in the md-dialog popup but I think it does not matter , probably depends on the function itself.

- I checked and there is no double controller in my code

Controller :

```
PanelCtrl.prototype.submit = function(data) {
  service.create(data).then(function(result){
        if(result.success === true)
        {
          service.add(data).then(function(result) {

              mdpanel && mdpanel.close().then(function() {
              });

            }).catch(function(){

              mdpanel && mdpanel.close().then(function() {
              });
            });

        }

  });

};
```

Service:

```
  return API.get('url').then(function (result) {

            if(typeof result.data !== "undefined" &&  result.data){
                return result.data;
            }

            return [];
        });
```

API get function:

```
  function get(q,url) {
            return $http.get(url +q).then(function (results) {
                return results.data;
            });
        }
```

1 request :

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
```

second:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 37
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Inspect what are these requests - if first is 'OPTIONS' and 2nd is 'GET' -- it is desired.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov no, double post , I added to the qeustion